# Hide model fields based on user permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

Lets say ***user_one has permission to*** view `purchase_price`,
and ***user_two*** does not have this permission.

I want to dynamically hide the `purchase_price` based on the user permission.

> What I have done

I already managed the permissions using **spatie package**.

> What I have tried and searched for

- I have found that I could use the `boot()` function the model itself to hide certain fields but I don't know how or it is the best solution also it is a `static function`.
- I could make a `scope` to handle what the API response using `if statements` and `select()` but I don't think this is a good solution too.
- Also I could use `Laravel resources`.

Comment: Some codes please. No free & effortless consultancy is available here on SO.

Comment: You don't need code to answer my question. I am asking about best practice in hiding some model fields from unauthorized users

Comment: Best practices I already shared in my solution but you need to read about them by your self. Because policies is a huge topic and can't explain everything at stack overflow.

Comment: So please read it and mark my solution correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create policies and after that use `can()` in the controller and `@can` in blade file for role filters.
[Click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies) for more information.

```
if ($this->getAuthorisedApp()->cannot('purchase_price'))
    {
        $this->setHidden(['purchase_price']);

        //  Or, $this->setVisible(['example_key']), if this works better for you.
    }
```

Comment: I am asking about hiding some model fields for some permissions.

Comment: @Danny, You need to read about policies. You can manage everything from policies eg: Model, Controller, Blade, Middleware. They work everywhere.

Comment: For more reference use this link:- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hide-eloquent-fields-based-on-user-role-or-any-model

Comment: I have created a policy and did as you tell me but I don't know how to fire that policy in the Model

Comment: Actually, I'm stuck somewhere. It's better if you can read yourself. Otherwise, I'll reply to you later.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.